# Comand over SSH to CentOS and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos, centos5

I want to put a command over SSH to my CentOS server;

Are the comands for CentOS same with Ubuntu? 
Are the following commands work for CentOS?
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/basic-commands/C/index.html

if not 
where can I find the documentation of CentOS Comands?

Comment: Both are Linux.... both will likely use bash as default shell....other commands depend on which software you have installed (obviously). The homepage is http://www.centos.org/

Comment: Are the following commands work for CentOS?
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/basic-commands/C/index.html

Comment: Why don't you just try them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are Linux distributions. The bash commands are the same for each distribution. There are eventually differences in shell script syntax depending on the shell version you are using (bash, ksh, zsh, ...).

For what concern SSH, it shouldn't have different syntax or options. The only thing you need eventually to check if the SSH version is the same on both machines. Very old version of SSH may have different options and feature, but this isn't dependend from the linux distribution.